# How to pass request Id value to modal?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

When I click on 'edit' button  modal is open 
but in a hidden field no I can't receive RequestId.
Please help me how to pass dynamic requested to modal form?

This I will use in Codeigniter framework.

If it is possible to please rewrite the code I will be most helpful.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" align="left">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Request Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Agent Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Comment</th>
            <th scope="col"> Request Date & Time</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
          $sn=1;
          foreach ($result as $row) { 
              //print_r($row);die();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $sn ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['aid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comment'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['request_time'];?></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Open</button></td>
            <td>
              <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php base_url()?>#myModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $sn++;}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where are your Modal code?where is your js code which you code so far

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, you wanted to display a modal after clicks on the edit button.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="get_modal_details('<?php echo $row['rid'];?>')" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

I hope `$row['rid']` is your unique ID and here is a html modal code

```html
<div class="modal" id="detail_modal_pop" style="overflow: scroll;"> 
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"> 
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" >
            <button type="button" class="close close_c_modal" >&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title c_modal">Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
             <h6 id="load_wait" class="text-center">Please wait...</h6>
             <div id="detail_modal_pop_result" style="display:none;"></div> 
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close_c_modal" >Close</button>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

To display a modal on clicks on edit button, use below script

```html
<script>
function get_modal_details(rid) 
{  
    $('#detail_modal_pop').fadeIn(200);  
    $("#detail_modal_pop_result").hide();
    $("#load_wait").show(); 
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>some_controller/controller_method", 
    data: { rid: rid },
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#load_wait").hide(); 
        $("#detail_modal_pop_result").show();
        $("#detail_modal_pop_result").html(data); 
    },
    error:function (){}
    }); 
} 
$(".close_c_modal").on("click", function() 
{
    $('#detail_modal_pop').fadeOut(200); 
    $("#detail_modal_pop_result").hide(300);
    $('#detail_modal_pop_result').html('');
    $("#load_wait").show(300);
}); 
 </script>
```

And here is the PHP code

```html
<?php
//"Some_controller.php" Controller

public function controller_method()
{
   if(isset($_POST['rid']))
   {
      $rid = (int)$_POST['rid']; 

      // $get_info = $this->Model->get_info($rid);  
      // Write modal content here...   
     
   }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But include the bootstrap cdn for above modal.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
data-request-id="<?php echo $row['rid']?>"
```

to the buttons that open the modals, and than use jquery/javascript to fetch the data with ajax

```
var requestId = $('.modalBtn').attr("data-request-id");
```

Comment: what is modalBtn  ??

Comment: Ah yea, sorry for being unclear, modalBtn should be the button you use to open the modal, in your case it is probalby this: <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php base_url()?>#myModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>, you can add another class to it to target it with js.

Answer (score 0):

The is a sample to pass the ID to modal by using [HTML data-attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) & jQuery.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" align="left">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Request Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Agent Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Comment</th>
            <th scope="col"> Request Date & Time</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        $sn=1;
        foreach ($result as $row) { 
            //print_r($row);die();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $sn ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['aid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comment'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['request_time'];?></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Open</button></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['rid'];?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $sn++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var $btn = e.relatedTarget,
        rId = $btn.data('id');

        // "rId" would be the value from the html data-attribute.
        console.log(rId);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" align="left">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Request Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Agent Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Comment</th>
            <th scope="col"> Request Date & Time</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
          $sn=1;
          foreach ($result as $row) { 
              //print_r($row);die();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $sn ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['aid'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comment'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['request_time'];?></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Open</button></td>
            <td>
              <a onclick="load_item('<?php echo $row['rid'];?>');" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $sn++;}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript Code You had to insert

```
 function load_item(rid){
/**
Write your ajax/javascript code here
*/
$("#myModal").modal("show");
 }
```

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: sure.. instead of targeting modal id, call function on click of link, pass the id to that link. In jquery you can either assign that value to that input which you get from function. or if you want dynamic modal you can create modal html & load it through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-toggle="modal"` from `<a>` tag and make `onclick` edit based on ID

```
<td>
  <a id="edit-form" href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
$('#edit-form').click(function() {
   $('#hidden_field_id').val(your-value);
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```